# ParticleJS with Liquid

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add Particle.JS as a background effect for my shopify store. The problem is that the canvas generated by particle js gets positioned below the divs which are the sections of the store. If I move it up manually before the divs it displays correctly.

Moved up manually: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfcj7.png)

Generated canvas: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqvyu.png)

CSS:

```
#particles-js canvas {
position: absolute !important;
z-index: -2;
vertical-align: top:

}

#particles-js {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  background-image: url("");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  z-index: -2;

}
```

HTML:

```
<main class="main-content js-focus-hidden" id="MainContent" role="main"     
 tabindex="-1">
 <script        
 src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
       <div id="particles-js">
       <canvas class="particles-js-canvas-el" width="100%" height="100%" style="width: 100%; height: 
       100%;"></canvas>
       {{ content_for_layout }} 
       </div>
       </main>

       {% section 'footer' %}

       <div id="slideshow-info" class="visually-hidden" aria-hidden="true">
       {{- 'sections.slideshow.navigation_instructions' | t -}}
       </div>

       </div>
```

ParticleJS: https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/blob/master/particles.js

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've messed around with the position tag, only thing that works is relative for the div container or else it gets messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by closing of the div before {{ content_for_layout }}, don't let people charge you $70 for fixing this as this was the quote I got from theme experts.

```
  <div class="page-container drawer-page-content" id="PageContainer">

<main class="main-content js-focus-hidden" id="MainContent" role="main" tabindex="-1">
  <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
  <div id="particles-js"></div>

  {{ content_for_layout }} 
 
</main>


{% section 'footer' %}

<div id="slideshow-info" class="visually-hidden" aria-hidden="true">
  {{- 'sections.slideshow.navigation_instructions' | t -}}
</div>
```